# How to restore sent dbx files to outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-express

I have currently upgraded from Outlook Express to Outlook 2010.

I am writing to seek assistance on the following issue below:

In Outlook 2010, I can not see any previous sent emails, I sent from Outlook Express in my Outlook 2010.

Is there any to retrieve my sent emails from Outlook Express into Outlook 2010?

Any help would be very much appreciated.